# how to solve change base url in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with mamp server, my last base url in confiq file is

```
http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/'
```

and my whole website is working properly.but now i am changed my config base url to

```
http://localhost:8888/lalcoresidency/'
```

so only my home page is working properly and when i clicked any other page then it show this error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /codeigniter/index.php was not found on this server.
```

please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: What is your project folder name in MAMP?

Comment: lalcoresidency same as url

Comment: When I load on local host the home page is working but when i clicked like room page then it show error

Comment: What the site_url() display?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/lalcoresidency/rooms

Comment: Is the browser URL showing correctly? Check whether you give the base_url hard coded some where.

Comment: If you have an .htaccess file, then check the url name there also.

Comment: I didnt understand arun

Comment: Are you using ".htaccess" file for hide the "index.php" part of your website? If so, check that also

Comment: Thanx alot arun . In .htaccess file i didnt change..now its working

Comment: With pleasure. Happy to help